# JavaFX KeyEvent doesn't do anything

Tags: javafx, keyevent

So I have a little program where you can fly your spaceship between planets and I want to use the arrow keys to rotate the ship. First I tried adding the key listener to the panel and the ship did rotate, but only when I pressed ctrl/alt. Then I tried adding the key listener to the scene instead (which people say is the right thing to do because it doesn't depend on focus), but although the function that rotates the ship is called, you can't see anything on the screen.

The main class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        loader.setController(controller);
             
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();
        controller.setScene(scene);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
}
```

The controller:

```
    @FXML
    private BorderPane contentPane;
    
    private OrbiterPanel orbiterPanel = new PerfectCirclePanel(this);
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        contentPane.setCenter(orbiterPanel);
    }

    public void setScene(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> keyStrokesPressed(e));
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> keyStrokesReleased(e));
    } 
    
    private void keyStrokesPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getCode()) {
        case LEFT -> {
            orbiterPanel.leftPressed();
        }
        case RIGHT -> {
            orbiterPanel.rightPressed();
        }
        default -> {}
        }   
    }
    
    private void keyStrokesReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getCode()) {
        case LEFT -> {
            orbiterPanel.leftReleased();
        }
        case RIGHT -> {
            orbiterPanel.rightReleased();
        }
        default -> {}
        }
    }
```

The superclass of all my "worlds/maps":

```
protected AtomicReference<Spaceship> shipReference = new AtomicReference<>();
    
    protected RotateTransition rotatingTransition;
    
    public OrbiterPanel() {
        rotatingTransition = new RotateTransition();
        rotatingTransition.setCycleCount(RotateTransition.INDEFINITE);
        rotatingTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    }
    
    protected void rightPressed() {
        if(rotatingTransition.getStatus().equals(Status.RUNNING)) return;
        rotatingTransition.stop();
        rotatingTransition.setNode(shipReference.get());
        rotatingTransition.setByAngle(360);
        rotatingTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        rotatingTransition.play();
    }
    
    protected void leftPressed() {
        if(rotatingTransition.getStatus().equals(Status.RUNNING)) return;
        rotatingTransition.stop();
        rotatingTransition.setNode(shipReference.get());
        rotatingTransition.setByAngle(-360);
        rotatingTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        rotatingTransition.play();
    }
    
    protected void rightReleased() {
        rotatingTransition.stop();
    }
    
    protected void leftReleased() {
        rotatingTransition.stop();
    }
```

PerfectCirclePanel, a subclass of OrbiterPanel doesn't really do much besides displaying the spaceship and a planet.
FXML:

```
<BorderPane prefHeight="607.0" prefWidth="877.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <center>
      <BorderPane fx:id="contentPane" prefHeight="704.0" prefWidth="963.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;">
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Post the FXML. You need to set the controller before loading the FXML, otherwise the `@FXML`-annotated fields won't be injected, and `initialize()` won't be invoked.

Comment: I don't think so... do you mean before calling loader.load()? That causes an error and as it is right now, it can use the contentPane from the FXML file, I believe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, before calling `loader.load()`. You don't use `contentPane` anywhere in the code you posted. What is the error; fixing that error will likely fix the underlying issue.

Comment: In the controller, I add the OrbiterPanel to the contentPane and if I set the controller before calling loader.load() it causes an Exception: "javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified."

Comment: Yes, but `initialize()` is never called on the `Controller` instance you create in code. I see the other problem now you've posted the FXML; if you are setting the controller in Java code, you must not have a `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML. Move the `setController()` call and remove that attribute.

Comment: Added an answer with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways to connect a controller to the UI defined by an FXML file.

**Either**:

1. Specify the controller class by providing a `fx:controller` attribute to the root element of the FXML. In this case, by default, a controller instance will be created from that class by invoking its no-argument constructor, and that instance will be the controller associated with the UI.

**Or**:

2. Call `setController(...)` on the `FXMLLoader` instance.

When you call `loader.load()`, if a controller exists, any `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller will be initialized from the corresponding FXML elements, and then the `initialize()` method will be called.

In your code, you create two `Controller` instances: one is created from the `fx:controller` attribute, and associated with the UI. The other you create "by hand" in the Java code. The latter is not connected to the UI (the `@FXML`-annotated fields are not injected, and `initialize()` is not invoked), because you call `setController(...)` *after* calling `load()`.

Because there are two `Controller` instances, there are two `OrbiterPanel` instances. The one created from the `fx:controller` attribute is the one displayed in the UI (because that's the one referenced when `initialize()` is invoked). The one created from the `Controller` instance you create in code is not displayed; however that is the one referenced by your event handler.

Remove the `fx:controller` attribute, and move the call to `setController()` before the call to `load()`.